# Unable to install provider hosted app in office 365 site

Tags: sharepoint-online, provider-hosted-app

I am working on provider hosted app using office 365 environment.

If I click on `f5` then it is working fine, so now I want to publish app to my Office 365 site.

I have created .app file and app catalog site on office 365 and successfully uploaded it also.

Initially I tried directly install it but it gave this error

> SharePoint 2013 the specified application identifier  is invalid
>   or does not exist

So then I thought to make entries in `appregnew.aspx`, but not able to that also,it is giving unexpected error occurred,I am giving the same clientId and SecretQuestion,the one which is I am using in my visual studio solution.

App Domain I am giving `<mysiteName>.sharepoint.com`

please guide me so that I can continue my work ,let me know if I am doing any wrong steps.

I am using iisexpress to host the site on local environment.

Comment: It Sound you will Aquarell your own appid to the sharepoint. I Aliase let sharepoint generate them for me.

Answer (score 1):

Go to `YOURWEBSITEURL/_layouts/15/appregnew.aspx` and get Client ID and `Client Secret` for your hosted app and then use these in your provider hosted app.

In your App code, Open your web.config and add the following code in **appsettings** tag.

```
<add key="ClientId" value="CLIENT_ID_KEY" />
<add key="ClientSecret" value="CLIENT_SECRET" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example where I am installing provider hosted app in office 365 BUT my application is running in Windows Azure. It is a step by step walk-through. Check if that help you

[How-to-creating-Provider-hosted-apps-for-SharePoint-2013](http://tech.just4sharing.com/Pages/tech/How-to-creating-Provider-hosted-apps-for-SharePoint-2013.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You should first register your app in appregnew.aspx page then update your client id while creating your app package and also update the same in Web.Config of web project. If you are attaching a Remote event receiver with your List/Library then you have to publish you web project to Azure then only you can install the app package otherwise if you are using localhost then it will gives you error on app install event.